# Using Indirect Variables in function with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to do a function that, when I am giving the name of a categorical variable, it filters all data that this variable has (like the zone where is from, lenght, etc). The thing is that I cannot fix the error I am getting:

```r
myddt <- function(df = dk, SPECIES = "DOG"){
    df1 <- df %>% filter(.data[[SPECIES]])
}
```

It says DOG not found in data. But it is a SPECIES in the dk file. I know I can do SPECIES == "DOG" and use .data{{SPECIES}}, but I wanted to try to use the format of a categorical value.

Comment: Your `filter`  is not taking a logical expression.  Perhaps you need `SPECIES == !! SPECIES)`  I would change the argument name to a different one instead of the same as column name in the data

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to use the same argument name as the column name as this can lead to evaluation issues.  In addition, the `filter` step in OP's post is not creating a logical expression.  Either evaluate (`!!`) or use `.env`

```
library(dplyr)
myddt <- function(df = dk, SPECIES = "DOG"){

   df %>% 
    filter(SPECIES == !! SPECIES)

}
```

---

Reproducible example

```
myddt <- function(df, Species = "setosa"){

   df %>% 
       filter(Species ==  .env$Species)

}
```

-testing

```
> myddt(iris,  "setosa")
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
11          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2  setosa
13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1  setosa
14          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
17          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4  setosa
18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa
19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa
20          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3  setosa
21          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2  setosa
22          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4  setosa
23          4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2  setosa
24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa
25          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2  setosa
26          5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2  setosa
27          5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4  setosa
28          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2  setosa
29          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2  setosa
30          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2  setosa
31          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2  setosa
32          5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
33          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1  setosa
34          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
35          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
36          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2  setosa
37          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2  setosa
38          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1  setosa
39          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
40          5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa
41          5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3  setosa
42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
43          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
44          5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6  setosa
45          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4  setosa
46          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa
47          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2  setosa
48          4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2  setosa
49          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2  setosa
50          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: I made it work with .env$SPECIES. Thank you so much for your help!